# subversion control matlab

Tags: svn, matlab

Currently i am working on a project with Subversion control (SVN) integrated with matlab.

I want to get list of folders in the svn repository from  URL under one project but for different modules.

I have tried like this :

```
 % to read all modules from excel 

data = xlsread(modules.xlsx)

for i= 1:length(data)

    module_name = cell2mat(data(i,1));
    sys = module_name;

    % to get list of folders under each module

    !svn list https://xxxx.collab.net/svn/repos/sys/branches/pro/

end
```

my problem is how 'sys' can be changed in the URL such that i can have access to all modules.  currently it works only for one module ( if i replace 'sys'= module1)

Thank you in advance

Regards
bstar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
svnCmd = '!svn list https://xxxx.collab.net/svn/repos/sys/branches/pro/'; 
evalc(strrep(svnCmd, 'sys', sys)) '
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

instead of the URL address write:

```
['https://xxxx.collab.net/svn/repos/' module_name '/branches/pro/']
```

(module_name needs to be a string in order of it to work)

Comment: Dear nate, thanks for responding. But it didn't work with that.

Comment: @bstar, what is the class type of module_name ?

Comment: @ nate the class for moduele_name is char

Comment: @ nate did u consider the '!svn list' before the link ?

Comment: @bstar, I'm not familiar with the svn list command, but in Matlab these url addresses are also of type char. Therefor, something like ['http://....' char_variabe '/abcd/'] are also a char type. Have you checked this FEX option: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11596-subversion-interface-for-matlab ? (doesn't work on windows though). And there's also this matlab GUI http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23508-subversion-gui ...

Comment: @ nate. here i have a solution for it from a friend. svnCmd = 'svn list https://xxxx.collab.net/svn/repos/sys/branches/pro/`; evalc(strrep(svnCmd, 'sys', sys))

'